# $L^p$ spaces and converging sequence in this space

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question about $L^p$ space which I kan not solve it could u plz help me:

let $(\Omega,A, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $1<p<\infty$.let $f_n$:$\Omega$ $\to$$\mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of measureable functions converging pointwise to f:$\Omega$$\to$ $\mathbb{C}$.assume that $\mid f_n \mid $ < $g$ for some g$\in$ $ L^p(\Omega)$ and  show that $\mid\mid{f_n-f}\mid\mid$$_p$ $\to$ $0$  as n$\to$ $\infty$

Answer (score 1):

This is just the dominated convergence theorem. Since $|f_n - f|^p \le 2^p(|f_n|^p + |f|^p) \le 2^{p+1} |g|^p$ and $g^p \in L^1$ you have $$\lim \int |f_n - f|^p = \int \lim |f_n - f|^p = 0.$$